# Power Automate Desktop | Send Keystroke not working with ()

Tags: regex, special-characters, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm using PowerAutomate Desktop with Keystroke which does data entry on a website using data from Excel sheets.
It's working perfecting until an entry has ().
I need to send keystroke and keep the curl brackets ().
Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Followed steps in PU forum:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/Send-key-with-opening-bracket/m-p/2071733#M24317